# Importance of Backward and forward secrecy

Tags: protocol-design, security-definition

Which security feature is more important in security protocols being used in different applications? Forward Secrecy or Backward Secrecy

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39761/definitions-of-secrecy/62338#62338

Comment: What is more important probably depends on your threat model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definitions of secrecy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39761/definitions-of-secrecy)